# Conversion of ftz file to pdf

Tags: pdf, file-conversion

I have recently created my own family tree on an app. But the app has created the file in `ftz` format. I am really having a hard time to convert it to `pdf` format.

Can anyone help me with this.

If this question breaks the community guidelines, then i am extremely sorry, but i am really helpless.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the app can print ?

There are various implementations of 'print to PDF' some are built into the operating system, some are available as extras and have to be installed.

You haven't said what operating system this is for, so it's hard to guide you explicitly. Worst case, you can probably print to a PostScript file and then run that through Ghostscript to get a PDF file.

But printing to PDF from the application might give better results.

Comment: its an android app

Comment: Oh, well I don't really know then. Can the app even print at all ? If so you can 'probably' set up something with Google Cloud Print (if that still exists) but that's well outside my area of expertise.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitalgene.familytree&hl=en_IN

this is the app, i am using

Comment: Well its FAQ says it can't print and it also says no PDF output. So I don't think you are going to be able to create a PDF file from it. As far as I can see you have two option; reverse engineer the saved data format and create your own PDF. Alternatively, capture the screen and create a PDF from that. Of course it will be a PDF containing nothing but a bitmap image.

Comment: How can i reverse engineer a ftz file ? 
Any Suggestions

Comment: Umm, no not really. This **is** a site for developers, I'd have thought anyone using this site would be able to figure out how to reverse-enigneer a dataset. However; presumably the file contains the data you entered in your family tree. Open it and look for that data. Modify the data in the app, look to see what's changed, repeat until you understand the format. Of course the file format may well be compressed, in which case you'll need to identify the compression scheme, or even encrypted if the app maker is truly paranoid about people reverse-engineering their file format.

Comment: No, I was unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the app. I don't know how to convert it to PDF however I know how to look the data inside the file that could be useful to you. The .FTZ is a compressed file therefore you can change its filename to .ZIP thus why it's .FTZ (Family Tree Zip). When you extract the zip, you're going to find a "node.ftt" file which contains all the data. This file is originally a .TSV (Tab Separated Values) file because the content format is of that and .FTT probably stands for "Family Tree TSV". You can just look into the file using Notepad without changing the filename. In the file, each line/row represents a person or spouse dot (The dot that connects spouses in the app). In each line contains the generated ID, parents ID (spouse dot, optional), relative coordinates, name, birthday, and other data that I am not sure what. If you want to convert the file to PDF, first you'll need to transform those data into some kind of graphic. At this point I have no idea how.